# Change UDP port with iptables for VPN clients

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, firewall, iptables

**What I want to do is say that for all UDP connections on interface ppp0 that have a destination port of `53`, change that destination port to 1053.**

I am attempting to change the destination port of UDP packets for VPN clients connected via PPTP on Ubuntu.

This question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242772/using-iptables-to-change-a-destination-port
suggests that this can be done using NAT at the `--to-destination` option, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:1053
```

This does work but it changes the port for ALL packets going out on port `53` but I only want to change the port for some of my VPN clients who are connected on interface `ppp0-255` and IP range `192.168.0.10-255`.

I have tried adding the source into the statement, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.10 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:1053
```

This however does not appear to work and the VPN connections still go through to port `53`.